# Javascript background running code

Tags: javascript, background-process

Is there some sort of `window.onThis();` function that I can set so that my code runs in a loop in the background?

```
window.onload = function() {while(true) {console.log("Blah")}}
```

This makes the page unresponsive. What is the recommended method of doing this?

I feel something's going over my head. Perhaps I'm looking at it the wrong way.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript can only run one thread at a time, so when it is running `console.log ("Blah")` forever as fast as possible, it is unable to do anything else.

A better way would be to use `setInterval`, e.g.

```
var a  = setInterval(function () { console.log("blah"); }, 1000);
// Set the function to be called every 1000 milliseconds

//(optional) some time later
clearInterval(a);
// Stop the function from being called every second.
```

In general, a busy infinite loop ( `while (true) { ... }` ) is never a good idea.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval

Comment: How do Javascript/Canvas games update so fast? What do they do to update the display every frame yet not lag the page up?

Answer (score 0):

It makes the page unresponsive because you've created an infinite loop. The while loop condition will always be true therefore the loop will never stop running.

I think you are looking for setInterval(), see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval